# How do I manage with dynamic id's

Tags: javascript

I am automating a test case, where I need to focus on a link, then I have to click on a element say element id looks like `//table[@id='562']/tbody/tr/td[2]/img`, but the value inside quotes that is 562 is keep changing how can i find out and click that element.  Please can any body help me.

Comment: what test tool are you using? Selenium?

Comment: yeah.. am using selenium

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `this`:

```
element.onclick = function(){
  alert(this.id);
};
```

Comment: sorry am not getting how to use this can u explain me more clearly.. thank u

Answer (score 0):

Write the same value out to a variable and use that to find the element.

Comment: Thank u andy. but the problem is, in this test case am going to upload a file and those files arranged row wise. i have to search that document and click that elmenent mentioned above but once i uploaded a document it may come in any row and the id attribute contain any value. There is no order for the value.So i cant predict the value.. so is there any other solution... please..

Comment: How would you know which item to click?